# Mentor trigger ordering

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say my board is [Blade Instructor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlade%20Instructor%5d), [Boros Challenger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBoros%20Challenger%5d), and [Goblin Cratermaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGoblin%20Cratermaker%5d). Can I:

1. Attack with all three;
2. Two mentor triggers go on stack;
3. Stack triggers such that Blade Instructor's trigger goes first, have that target Boros Challenger;
4. Boros Challenger's mentor trigger targets Goblin Cratarmaker;
5. Both triggers see a valid target, therefore I end up with 3/1, 3/4 and 3/3?

I'm not sure if #2 actually works - it is possible that Boros Challenger's mentor ability won't trigger because it, at the time it goes on the stack, had no legal target (or does it trigger anyway, just not resolve?).

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, consider adding a comment? Is there something you think could have been fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can only get one Mentor trigger, the one from Blade Instructor.**

If a triggered ability that targets something does not have a legal target when it triggers, it will be removed from the stack as part of the triggering process, and you won't get a chance to resolve anything beforehand. This applies to Boros Challenger's ability as there is no legal target when it triggers.

> 603.3d The remainder of the process for putting a triggered ability on the stack is identical to the process for casting a spell listed in rules 601.2c–d. **If a choice is required when the triggered ability goes on the stack but no legal choices can be made for it, or if a rule or a continuous effect otherwise makes the ability illegal, the ability is simply removed from the stack.**